# Regex Memorize all matches before replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list list of 2 values separated by a comma like so:

```
A, 0xAA
B, 0xBB
C, 0xCC
```

etc. I want to use notepad++ and Regex to replace this list with a list of this form:

```
A-B-C
0xAA-0xBB-0xCC
```

The regex to match the pattern looks like this:

```
^(\w+), 0x(\w\w)$
```

But I don't know how to make notepad replace the matches in the way I described. It would have to memorize the matches or something like that, I'm not even sure how to describe this behaviour, which is probably why I didn't find a solution yet.

Comment: I had a similar problem and I solved with Excel, first split for ", " and then concatenate the column elments with your divider.

Comment: Just import into Excel, copy/paste each column into a new row transposing the contents, and then copy/paste the row into Notepad++ replacing all tabs with `-`s. Repeat with the 2nd column.

Comment: The Excel workaround does the job, but I'll leave the question open in case someone has a non-workaround answer.

Comment: I posted as an answer since it works, and might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

1.) Press and hold the `ALT`-Key, select your second column of elements:

[image]

2.) Cut (`CTRL+X)` and just paste bellow (`CTRL+V`)

[image]

3.) add a "hashtag" (or something else) between both areas

[image]

4.) Run Regex Replacement with: `,?\s+` (replacement `-`)

[image]

5.) replace `-#-` with a new line (`\r\n`):

[image]

Works for any number of rows and/or columns. just rinse and repeat step 1,2,3 finally followed by 4 and 5. Second Block becomes second row, third -> third and so on.

Comment: Neat, I didn't know the Alt+Selection method. I like this the best so far, however since its strictly speaking not a "regex-only" solution, I will wait little before accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround with Excel:

1. Paste the list in Excel
2. Select the column and select *Data* -> *Text to Columns*. Choose *Delimited*, set *Delimiters* to "Comma" and *Text qualifier* to {none}, use Text as type of data.
3. Copy Column 1 values ("A", "B", etc.) and paste with transposition onto a new row.
4. Repeat with Column 2.
5. Copy the 2 rows and paste into Notepad++, and replace all tabs with `-`.

Result:

```
A-B-C
0xAA-0xBB-0xCC
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated notepad++ isn't a good tool for this replace but if you really needed to use it, the pattern for your simple example would be large:

Pattern:

```
(\w)(,\s)(0x\w\w)\r\n(\w)(,\s)(0x\w\w)\r\n(\w)(,\s)(0x\w\w)
```

Replace with:

```
$1-$4-$7 \r\n$3-$6-$9
```

Comment: Is there a solution for n rows?

Comment: I don't think so, sorry.